# How to change ant output severity to error

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

We use ant build step in team city build configuration.
How can I change default log format that is present in Build Log. I am looking for solution to change some log lines to be reported as errors and not as default warning.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity fully relies on logging levels used by Ant. If Ant process logs something with severity "error", it will be rendered properly (red) and will cause build failures.

To log arbitrary line as error, please use `level` attribute in `echo` task:

`<echo level="error">This is a very bad error</echo>`